# Частичное разрешение зависимостей через DI фреймворки

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Не знаю на сколько это правильно, но хочу следующего:

Допустим, есть класс, который на вход конструктора принимает 3 аргумента.

`Interface1, Interface2, String`

Хочу, что бы DI контейнер зарезолвил первые 2 параметра, а второй мог передавать пользователь. Скажем, он обращается к контейнеру и говорит, "хочу что бы ты создал такой-то тип и передает дополнительный 3-й параметр"

Реализует ли какой-нибудь DI фреймворк такой функционал?

Как альтернативу, если такого нет или мой подход неверный(тогда предложите более верный вариант), я только вижу, после создания объекта дополнительно его донастраивать...

Comment: Честно говоря, мало я работал с DI, но на практике имел опыт с [UnityContainer](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity). Там в Resolve можно пропихивать ParameterOverrides, в которых ты указываешь имя аргумента и значение. Правда этот фреймворк устарел, но так-то рабочий. Пример [вот тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff660920(v=pandp.20)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) можешь поглядеть. Такую конструкцию в общем-то можно и в расширение запихнуть. Если ты по порядковому номеру аргумента хочешь - тут хз, а так можешь и в других фреймворках поискать похожие методы.

Comment: Что-то [такое](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html#passing-parameters-to-resolve) нужно?

Comment: Проще всего сделать фабрику, которая будет выпускать этот тип, пробрасывая ему полученный параметр. Это точно будет работать с любым контейнером.

Comment: *Скажем, он обращается к контейнеру и говорит* — т. е. у этого пользователя ещё и сам контейнер в зависимостях? Как по мне — хуже некуда.

Comment: @rdorn визуально похоже на то, что нужно. Т.е я могу сказать, что бы он разрезольвил часть параметров сам на основании зарегистрированных зависимостей, а потом ему при создании объекта передать какие-то доп. параметры?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ну... вариант с фабрикой неплох. Можете оформить ответом.

Comment: Unity такое точно поддерживает, остальные фреймворки должны поддерживать по идее. Очень удивлюсь, если такую базовую вещь кто то не будет поддерживать.

Comment: Всё зависит от того, что делает класс и зачем ему 3-й параметр. Возможно этому параметру просто не место в конструкторе, и он, например, должен передаваться через параметр метода (см. [DI Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/)). Фабрика в таком случае может быть ненужной дополнительной абстракцией.

Comment: Если же 3-й параметр каким-либо образом конфигурирует класс, то возможно целесообразнее будет определить класс настроек, поместив параметр в него.

Answer (score 4):

> Хочу, что бы DI контейнер зарезолвил первые 2 параметра, а второй мог передавать пользователь. Скажем, он обращается к контейнеру и говорит, "хочу что бы ты создал такой-то тип и передает дополнительный 3-й параметр"

Т. е. все пользователи класса должны еще и знать о контейнере и зависеть от него? Как по мне — выглядит плохо.

Я такие задачи обычно решаю с помощью фабрик, например, есть у вас класс:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public MyClass(IDependency1 dependency1, IDependency2 dependency2, string parameter)
    {
    }
}
```

Просто создаете фабрику:

```
public interface IMyClassFactory
{
    IMyClass Create(string parameter);
}

public class MyClassFactory : IMyClassFactory
{
    private readonly IDependency1 _dependency1;
    private readonly IDependency2 _dependency2;

    public MyClassFactory(IDependency1 dependency1, IDependency2 dependency2)
    {
        _dependency1 = dependency1;
        _dependency2 = dependency2;
    }

    public IMyClass Create(string parameter)
    {
        return MyClass(_dependency1, _dependency2, parameter);
    }
}
```

регистрируете ее в контейнере и во всех местах, где вам нужен экземпляр MyClass, объявляете зависимость от IMyClassFactory и пользуетесь ей:

```
var myClass = _myClassFactory.Create(parameter);
myClass.DoSomething();
```

Comment: то есть ваш DI контейнер никак не управляет временем жизни объекта `MyClass`?

Comment: @tym32167, нет, а должен?

Comment: с одной стороны нет, ведь у вас есть фабрика. Но, с другой стороны, я бы прокинул в эту фабрику сам контейнер и внктри вместо `return MyClass(_dependency1, _dependency2, parameter);` вызывал бы что то типа `_container.Resolve(/* my parameter */)`, чтобы само создание объекта так и лежало на плечах контейнера, а фабрика только подставляла только те зависимости, которых нет в контейнере. В этом случае, если какие то зависимости-сервисы будут изменены / добавлены в класс, вам не придется менять фабрику.

Comment: @tym32167, у фабрики единственная ответственность — выпускать экземпляры класса и единственная причина для изменения — когда меняются зависимости у этого выпускаемого класса. Так что проблем не вижу. Тянуть контейнер в фабрику считаю не нужно.

Comment: как я уже писал, с одной стороны - вы правы про фабрику. Но давайте подумаем о причине, зачем вы эту фабрику вообще создавали? Вы пишете `выпускать экземпляры класса` - но контейнер и так это может делать, то есть бессмысленно создавать фабрику для этого. Вы же её создаете, так как вам надо указать конкретный параметр при создании, а не выполнять само создание. Что я предлагаю - не расширять ответсвенность фабрики на само создание объекта, так как мы уже имеем такой функционал в контейнере. Это поможет избежать проблем если, например, мы захотим использовать перехватчики для нашего класса.

Comment: или, например, если мы захотим зарегистрировтаь другой класс в контейнере, вместо `MyClass`, или использовать любой другой функционал из контейнера при создания экземпляра для `IMyClass`

Answer (score 2):

Помимо *constructor injection* также применяют *property injection* и иногда даже *method injection*.

В данном случае налицо ситуация, где хорошо ложится *property injection*. Через конструктор передаём `interface` и `interface2`. Время жизни должно быть *transient*, чтобы всякий раз нам возвращался новый класс.

Ну а строковый параметр сделать свойством, доступным для записи. Тогда в классе `Foo`, где нам нужен класс, который надо донастроить, пишем что-то вроде:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly Bar _bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
        _bar.Baz = "Dow";
    }
}
```

Comment: Где-то слышал, что инъекция должна происходить только через конструктор, а все остальное от лукавого...

Comment: @iluxa1810 Все перечисленные методы описаны в книге Симана (https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/22104901/). Он ничего не пишет о том, что какие-то из этих методов *правильные*, а какие-то — нет.

Comment: Если эта дополнительная зависимость нужна только в одном методе, то лучше, наверное, инжектить прямо в него. Если в нескольких, то инъекция через свойство плоха тем, что в каждом методе придется проверять, а установили ли нам значение свойства

Comment: я всегда за внедрение только в конструктор, так как имея все зависимости в конструкторе можно легко понять, сколько зависимостей у класса. Внедряя зависимости в методы/свойства, мы скрываем пробему слишком большого количества зависимостей у класса. По моему это было у дяди Боба или у Фаулера, я точно не помню. Особенно, когда дело касается обязательных зависимостей, без которых класс не должен функционировать - с инъекцией её в свойство мы просто ломаем логику класса.