# WPW Prism & DryIoC constructor injection, есть ли?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, prism

Доброго времени суток.
Столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть интерфейс IDialogManager и его реализация DialogManager.
В DialogManager есть метод

```
public void ShowLogs(User user) { ... }
```

Вопрос следующий, как мне резолвить SignInLogsView внутри этого метода, если для SignInLogsView есть ViewModel, у которой в конструкторе есть параметр User, который передается в метод ShowLogs, который нужно пробросить во ViewModel. Перекопал уже весь гугл, ничего не нашел.
Главная проблема, что я резовлю View, а пробросить надо во ViewModel.

Придумал только 1 вариант:

```
var vm = container.Resolve<SignInLogsViewModel>(new[] { user });
var view = container.Resolve<SignInLogsView>();

view.DataContext = vm;
```

Но не думаю, что это лучший из возможных.

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1051111/218063

Comment: Не совсем, у меня немного другая проблема

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так

```
var user = new User() {Name = "Bob"};   
var view = container.Resolve<Func<User, SignInLogsView>>()(user);
```

Comment: Не то, обратите внимание, что у меня используется Prism framework.

Comment: можете поподробней. В чем конкретно проблема с prism?

Comment: У Prism есть AutoWireViewModel, при резолве View она сама устанавливает ViewModel, которую тоже сама резолвит, в этом главная проблема

Comment: так это надо указывать непосредственно в вопросе, это же важная часть вашего вопроса.

Comment: Возможно тут забыл указать это, думал, что "Prism" само за себя скажет, учту в будущем